# Fedora 14 - Error 5 - No space on Disk - After installation

Tags: linux, fedora, errno

I am new to Fedora, am still figure my way through it. I was going about tweaking it and preparing it to my needs, While installing through yum I dont have much other than the fact that I have to search for the packages. But when I open "Add/remove software" of Fedora. I am greeted with " No space left on the disk" and when I seek for more details it says " Disk Error :[errno 5] Input/output error"

I did some research and I saw that it usually occurs during installation, but here I have successfully installed it.

Can someone help me with it? Later on I even had notification of the same warning. And mind you I got loads of free space.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: This belongs on serverfault.com

Comment: Should I repost it there? Or Will Mods transfer it? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

your problem i think is your space disk like the error message said.

You can do:

```
# du -hsc /*

# df -h
```

and check result